# Get id product when using dropzone to upload multiple images laravel

Tags: php, laravel, dropzone.js

I'm a new Laravel.
Now, I want to create product and I'm using dropzone.js to upload multiple images.
I have Product table (name, sku, barcode,price, main_image,...) to store product and Product_images to store images of product.
[image]
`model_id` is idProduct. But I don't know store it when I create a new product

**My Routes**

```
Route::post('/products/upload/dropzone', 'ProductController@uploadDropzone')->name('be.upload.dropzone');
Route::post('/products/store', 'ProductController@store')->name('be.product.store');
```

**My Controllers - Upload Images**

```
public function uploadDropzone(Request $request) {
        $image = $request->file('others_image');
        if ($image) {
            $dropzone = new ProductImage;
            $imageName = $image->getClientOriginalName();
            $dropzone->image_name = $imageName;
            $image->move(realpath(public_path('uploads/images/product/product')), $imageName);
            $dropzone->image_path = 'uploads/images/product/product/'.$imageName;
            $dropzone->model = 'Product';
            $dropzone->model_id = ??;

            $dropzone->save();
        }

        return response()->json(['message' => 'Images uploaded successfully!']);
    }
```

**Script Dropzone**

```
Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;
        var myDropzone = new Dropzone("div#dropzone_images", {
            url: "{{ route('be.upload.dropzone') }}",
            sending: function(file, xhr, formData){
                formData.append('_token', $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content'));
            },
            paramName: 'others_image',
            addRemoveLinks: true,
            acceptedFiles: 'image/*',
            dictRemoveFile: 'Xóa ảnh',
        });
```

I have saved product information and product images but idProduct did not (`model_id`).

All comments are respected

Thanks so much!

Comment: upload images and response with the `product_image_ids`, post the product with these id, after create product, update the images' `model_id`

Comment: Thanks TsaiKoga, you can description details for this?

Answer (score 0):

Using session you can solve this problem. 
just put imageId in session then when you create product update that

---

**Controller**

```php
 public function uploadDropzone(Request $request) {
            $image = $request->file('others_image');
            if ($image) {
                $imageName = $image->getClientOriginalName();
                $image->move(realpath(public_path('uploads/images/product/product')), $imageName);
                $path = 'uploads/images/product/product/'.$imageName;

                $productImage = ProductImage::create([
                    'model' => 'Product',
                    'image_name' => $imageName,
                    'image_path' => $path
                ]);

                $request->session()->put('imageId', $productImage->id);
            }
            return response()->json(['message' => 'Images uploaded successfully!']);
        }
```

now in create.blade.php

```
 $productImageId = session()->get('imageId');

        $productImage = ProductImage::find($productImageId);

        $productImage->update([
            'model_id' => $id
        ]);

session()->forget('imageId');
```

https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/session

Comment: Thanks, Paul. But error: `Undefined variable: productId`. Any solution?

Comment: $productId u have to put based upon you product page ^_^ . check somewhere you may print product name or description on that page simillar you have to print product id

Comment: In my blade: `create.blade.php` ?

Comment: i thoght it's in edit.blade.php . do one thing whenever you are uploding image add an array in seesion that will contain ids of ProductImage then creating product update all model_id

Comment: Thanks, Paul, but error `Call to a member function update() on null`. Sorry, because I'm a new Laravel :(

Comment: @HoangDinh check some tutorial about update delete and create